# Retrofit Post Multipart Raw Data

Tags: android, retrofit, multipart

I am trying to send multipart post request using Retrofit, but I'm not able to do. Below is my post request data which I need to post into server using `multipart`.

```
{
   "name":"Akhil",
   "email":"akhil.garg@gmail.com",
   "password":"123456",
   "phoneNumber":"9988928289",
   "countryCode":"IN",
   "pincode":"wddw33",
   "latitude":321332.434,
   "longitude":232132121.44,
   "address":{
      "addressLine1":"efefewf",
      "addressLine2":"fefewffew"
   }
}
```

I am doing like this.

```
public interface RegisterInterface {

        @Multipart
        @POST("register")
        Call<Root> signUp(
                @Part("name") RequestBody name,
                @Part("email") RequestBody email,
                @Part("password") RequestBody password,
                @Part("phoneNumber") RequestBody phoneNumber,
                @Part("countryCode") RequestBody countryCode,
                @Part("pincode") RequestBody pincode,
                @Part("latitude") RequestBody latitude,
                @Part("longitude") RequestBody longitude,
                @Part("address") RequestBody address
                );

}

private void registerUser(String address){


        HashMap<String,String> address1= new HashMap();
        address1.put("addressLine1","B-184");
        address1.put("addressLine2","New Delhi");
        RequestBody uEmail = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("email"), email.getValue());
        RequestBody uname = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("name"), name.getValue());
        RequestBody upassword = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("password"), password.getValue());
        RequestBody phoneNumber = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("phoneNumber"), phoneNo.getValue());
        RequestBody countryCode = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("countryCode"), "IN");
        RequestBody pincode = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("pincode"), "110092");
        RequestBody latitude = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("latitude"), 24.0987+"");
        RequestBody longitude = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("longitude"), 43.09567+"");
        RequestBody uaddress = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("address"), data1);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiUrl.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        RegisterInterface vInterface = retrofit.create(RegisterInterface.class);
        RegisterationModel imageDataSet = new RegisterationModel(name.getValue(),phoneNo.getValue(),email.getValue(),password.getValue(),22.0987,43.09876,data1,"IN","110092");

        Call<Root> serverCom = vInterface.signUp(uname,uEmail,upassword,phoneNumber,countryCode,pincode,latitude,longitude,uaddress);
        serverCom.enqueue(new Callback<Root>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Root> call, Response<Root> response) {
                //Data result = response.body().getData();

                Log.d("Result",response.body()+"");
                if (response!=null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "File Successfully Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Root> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: where is `MultipartBody.Part` finalFile??

Comment: all data I need to send in multipart

Comment: Where your file data?

Comment: there is no any file data. I just need to post these data

Comment: `A HTTP multipart request is a HTTP request that HTTP clients construct to send files. `

Comment: ok, if there will be a file then how to do that?

Comment: you should add `@Part  MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload` where fileToUpload is key name. Set your key name.

Comment: Please check my answer hope it will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

If there will be file then..

```
 MultipartBody.Part userImage = null;
 File file = new File(model.getReceipt());
 RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file);
 userImage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(ApiConstants.RECEIPT, file.getName(), requestFile);
```

pass `userImage` as parameter in your Api call...
If there will be only data then...

```
HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("id", RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, String.valueOf(invoice_id)));
```

pass `map` as parameter in your Api call...